# iOS: Trigger push notification from app programatically using Amazon SNS

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

Is there any code which clarifies how to send push notifications to a device directly from code, knowing that I am using `Amazon SNS`, such that the push notification is triggered from the app?

I added all devices data to `SNS console` (token..), and couldn't find any clear document which resolved this issue.

Comment: Please explain what you need exactly and how it is related to objective-c tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
AWSSNS *publishCall = [AWSSNS defaultSNS];

AWSSNSPublishInput *message = [AWSSNSPublishInput new];

message.subject = @"My First Message";


//This is the ending point
message.targetArn = @"arn:aws:sns:eu-west-X:xxxxxxxxx:endpoint/APNS_SANDBOX/AmazonTest/aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaaaa-aaaaaa";
message.subject =@"hello";
message.message =self.textField.text;
//    message.messageAttributes = messageDict;
//
//    message.messageStructure = jsonString;
if ([self.textField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
    //nothing
}else

[publishCall publish:message completionHandler:^(AWSSNSPublishResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if(error) NSLog(@"%@", [error userInfo]);
    if(response) NSLog(@"%@", [response description]);
}];
```